# How to move a file into an existing Jar using Ant

Tags: java, jar, ant

Can anyone please explain to me what thatt code do :`<target name="MoveFIle">             <exec executable="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_131\\bin\\jar" dir="${basedir}/classes/">         <arg value="-uf" />                    <arg value="${basedir}/test.jar" />                <argvalue="Test.class" />      </exec>`

Iw there any possibility to move the file into a special path when the Jar is unzipped ?

Answer (score 0):

jar -uf .../test.jar Test.class

according documetation "Updates an existing file jarfile (when f is specified) by adding to it files and directories specified by inputfiles."

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html

Comment: I tried to add it but an error occured that the file dont exist

Comment: I also tried to unzip and copy ant i have an error

<target name="T0">
  <mkdir dir="C:\Users\Jars"/>
  <unzip src="C:\Users\Test\bin\HelloWorld.jar" dest="C:\Users\Jars"/> 
  <copy overwrite="true" todir="C:\Users\Jars" >
    <path>
       <pathelement path="${build.dir}/tst2.class"/>
     </path>
  </copy>
 </target>